# Unable to mount external HDD due to unknown filesystem

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I recently reformatted my laptop. Beforehand I backed up all my data on a external hdd. Before doing this, I completely reformatted my external hdd using the Disk Manager and created a new Linux Filesystem partition. I then moved all data on to the hdd. I had no problems mounting or accessing files on the hdd. However, after reformatting the laptop and reinstalling Ubuntu I can no longer mount the hdd.

Output `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 00007F4F-6548-0000-8534-0000C2310000

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1465149134 1465147087 698,7G Linux filesystem
```

Output `parted`:

```
Model: APPLE HD D HTS547575A9E38 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  750GB  750GB
```

Update: This is what happens when I try to mount

$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

```
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

@9291Sam Yes, I meant GNOME Disks

Comment: What happens when you try to mount it? How are you doing that? Any error messages?

Comment: How did you make a Linux filesystem partition from Microsoft windows Disk manager

Comment: @9291Sam, he didn't say Windows... I'm sure he meant the Gnome Disk manager.

Comment: This is what happens when I try to mount it:

$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

@9291Sam Yes, I meant GNOME Disks

Answer (score 2):

Try the syntax

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

assuming the filesystem is ext4

Comment: Output:

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

Comment: That sounds bad.

Comment: Nothing that can be done?